Derivation of gyrocenter speed in gradient magnetic field, doubt in resolution differential equation with slow time variation force
I was reading Paul M. Bellan's book:"Fundamentals of Plasma Physics. Cambridge University Press, 2006.", the chapter "Drifts in slowly changing arbitrary fields", in particular the derivation of the perpendicular component of the gyrocenter speed $v_{\perp GC}$ in a gradient magnetic field. I'm only interested in how they solved the differential equation \ref{eq:3.72}. The text is as follow:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.71}
m[\frac{d\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}(t)}{dt}+v^2_{||gc}\hat{B}\cdot\nabla\hat{B}]=q[\textbf{E}_\perp(\textbf{x}_{gc}(t))+\textbf{v}_{gc}(t)\times \textbf{B}(\textbf{x}_{gc}(t))+\langle \textbf{v}_L(t)\times (\textbf{r}_L(t)\cdot \nabla)\textbf{B} \rangle]\tag*{(3.71)}
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{eq:3.71} is of the generic form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.72}
m\frac{d\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}(t)}{dt}=\textbf{F}_{\perp}+q\textbf{v}_{gc}×\textbf{B}\tag*{(3.72)}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.73}
\textbf{F}_{\perp} = q[\textbf{E}_\perp(\textbf{x}_{gc}(t))+\langle \textbf{v}_L(t)\times (\textbf{r}_L(t)\cdot \nabla)\textbf{B} \rangle]-v^2_{||gc}\hat{B}\cdot\nabla\hat{B}. \tag*{(3.73)}
\end{equation}
Equation \ref{eq:3.72} is solved iteratively based on the assumption that $\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}$ has a slow time dependence. In the first iteration, the time dependence is neglected altogether so that the left-hand side of Eq. \ref{eq:3.72} is set to zero to obtain the “first guess” for the perpendicular drift to be
\begin{equation}
\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}\simeq \textbf{v}_F \equiv \frac{\textbf{F}_{\perp}\times\textbf{B}}{qB^2}
\end{equation}
Next, $\textbf{v}_p$ is defined to be a correction to this first guess, where $\textbf{v}_p$ is assumed small and incorporates effects due to any time dependence of $\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}$. To determine $\textbf{v}_p$, we write $\textbf{v}_{\perp gc}=\textbf{v}_F+\textbf{v}_p$ so, to second order Eq. \ref{eq:3.72} becomes
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.74}
m\frac{d(\textbf{v}_{F}+\textbf{v}_{p})}{dt}=\textbf{F}_{\perp}+q(\textbf{v}_{F}+\textbf{v}_{p})×\textbf{B}\tag*{(3.74)}
\end{equation}
In accordance with the slowness condition, it is assumed that $|d\textbf{v}_p/dt|\ll |d\textbf{v}_F /dt|$ so Eq. \ref{eq:3.74} becomes
\begin{equation}\label{eq:3.75}
0=-m\frac{d\textbf{v}_F}{dt}+q\textbf{v}_{p}×\textbf{B}\tag*{(3.75)}
\end{equation}

I want to ask about how they solved the differential equation \ref{eq:3.72}. From what I understand they used perturbation theory to solve it, where $\textbf{v}_F$ is the zero order solution while $\textbf{v}_p$ is the first order one. Is this correct?
If that's the case $\textbf{v}_F$ should be the solution in the case $\textbf{F}_{\perp} = cost$. The problem arise when they solve Eq. \ref{eq:3.74} and obtain Eq. \ref{eq:3.75}, here I find 2 problems:

They used the equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
0=q\textbf{v}_{F}×\textbf{B}+\textbf{F}_{\perp} \quad \textrm{with} \quad \textbf{F}_{\perp} = cost \tag*{(1)}
\end{equation}
but in Eq. \ref{eq:3.74}, since $\textbf{F}_{\perp}$ is our perturbation term and is a function of time, I shouldn't be able to use \ref{eq:1};

Moreover in \ref{eq:3.75} shouldn't $\frac{d\textbf{v}_F}{dt}=0$ since they said "the time dependence is neglected altogether" when solving for $\textbf{v}_F$?


Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

You separate the guiding center motion from the gyromotion.  I am not sure if that's considered a perturbative approach or not, but that is what most people do.  You can also directly integrate 3.72 if you know the electric and magnetic fields as functions of position and time ;)

The equations are already the result of the separation between the guiding center motion from the gyromotion. I don't understand why they consider $v_F$ a costant in Eq. (1) and then in Eq. (3.75) is not a costant anymore

It's not a constant, rather the changes are slow relative to something else thus the dv/dt term can be dropped (my quick-glance-guess but it's been a few decades since I did this exercise)...

Exactly, I thought about that too, the problem is that in Eq. (3.74) I'm considering Eq.(1) to be true and so, like you said, it means $\frac{d\textbf{v}_F}{dt}$ term can be dropped, but that would mean I should also drop the same term $\frac{d\textbf{v}_F}{dt}$ on the left side of (3.74) no?

If I am reading things correctly and your notes accurately reflect Paul's book, then $\mathbf{v}{p} \times \mathbf{B}$ is large compared to $\mathbf{v}{F} \times \mathbf{B}$, but $\lvert d \mathbf{v}{p}/dt \rvert \ll \lvert d \mathbf{v}{F}/dt \rvert$.  One way to do this is that most of $\mathbf{v}_{F}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{B}$, which is often the case.  It's not completely general but it is often true in regions with large background magnetic fields (i.e., large compared to perturbations).
